# Show all options in select list does not work when there's only one option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page where I show list of strings (strings are fetched from API call). They are presented as select/option tags and I need to show ALL options (they should not be hidden). To make it possible I specify `size` attribute in select tag. Here's the code:

html:

```
<select size="2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

css:

```
  select {
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #08112d;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
  option {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
```

[example on fiddle which works](https://jsfiddle.net/advzjh1m/)

[image]

**The problem**

If there's only one option in the list, then the styles are broken and select list requires a click to see options, which is something that I don't want. How to fix it?

[example on fiddle which has broken styles](https://jsfiddle.net/advzjh1m/1/)

[image]

**P.S.**
I need to use select/options tags as I need their behavior (like selectable options and possibility to choose options with arrow up button ⬆ and arrow down ⬇). So I cannot use other tags (unless you can suggest how to add such behavior then).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the HTML of your broken example and it is the following:

```
<select size="1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

can you try the following **instead**:

```
<select size="1" multiple>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

as you can see [in the following docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_size.asp) when using multiple it sets the size to 4 elements but still since we're forcing to keep 1 it fixes the issue

Comment: but then I have 2 same options...

Comment: @humanbean no idea what you're trying to say

Comment: @devnullΨ can you try the updated solution?

Comment: yes updated one worked !

Answer (score 1):

Note `size="1"` does not create consistent result across browsers according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-size)

If limiting the height is an option you can keep `size="2"` even there's a single option. And use css to set the correct display.

```css
  select {
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #08112d;
    max-height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
select.single {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2d0811;
    min-width: 40px;
    max-height: 51px;
  }
option {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1rem;
}
option:hover {
  background-color: #6b7081;
}
```

```html
<select size="2" class="single">
  <option value="1" >1</option>
</select>

<select size="2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

add multiple attribute to select tag

```
<select size="1" multiple>
   <option value="1">1</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: how does this fix an issue?

Comment: it works without multiple tag but not on size ="1" does not create consistent result across browsers according. when add multiple attribute it fixed.

Comment: Note: with multiple attribute on select user can select multiple options and if you dont need to be like that you simply can use radio btn

Comment: but to make it work with size 1 is what I needed

Comment: it works also with size 1 just add multiple attribute on select it working